# Get ACF OEmbed URL without returning iFrame using Timber

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I have a semi complicated flexible content component that accesses a postObject which includes an oembed ACF field.

In other words Flexible Content -> PostObject -> OEmbed

But I'd like to extract the raw OEmbed url to put into its own clickable link that will send people to the video source.

I've looked at these issues:

https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/1211

https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/1423

which are similar, but don't seem to be working in my case.

Is there a way to

A) Pull out the link in the Twig template or

 B) Extend Timber to return just the link somewhere in the PostObject?

Comment: see https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/oembed/

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the oEmbed without the iframe formatting by passing `false` as a 3rd parameter to the `get_field` function.

```
// Load oEmbed URL
$iframeUrl = get_field('oembed', false, false);
```

More info on the [ACF Functions Docs page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest extracting the link in you php and then adding it to context:

```
// Load value.
$iframe = get_field('oembed');

// Use preg_match to find iframe src.
preg_match('/src="(.+?)"/', $iframe, $matches);
$src = $matches[1];

// Add to timber/twig context
$context['iframe_src'] = $src
```